# How can I make rm stop asking me for permission?

Tags: rm

On my server rm always asks me for permission (even though I'm root) when I run it, on my desktop it does not. Like so:

```
$ rm mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz
rm: remove regular file `mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz'?
```

How do I make it stop prompting me?

Comment: Maybe it is an alias. List the aliases with `alias` and remove the alias with `unalias rm`.

Comment: Just remember that if you break your system, you get to keep both pieces. You might want to switch to something like `trash-cli` to give yourself an undo button for deletion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would check if your `rm` is an alias. Typing `alias` at the command line you will see all defined aliases. I expect something like

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

If so, the alias is probably defined in in `~/.bashrc`, so you can remove the alias altogether or change it to suit your needs.

Alternatively, you can remove the alias for the current terminal session using `unalias rm`.

Comment: I consider it wiser to leave this as is and always use rm (-i due to the alias) and when prompted either type yes or ctrl-c and than do a rm -f. Safety first: I borked a complete system using rm where it did not have -i cuz someone else removed it from aliases (otherwise I would have spotted my mistake :D ).

Comment: @Rinzwind - You are probably right, but I'm not overly worried about borking my server system in this case. It's stateless and I have setup script to restore it. I did however once remove half the PHP libs from my system through a badly typed rm, but I find it less annoying to do a big cleanup once, than small things all the time.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but if you’re not yet experienced enough to find out that your `rm` is an alias, then you should probably leave safety measures in place.

Answer (score 12):

`rm -f mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz`

WARNING: use with caution.

From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm):

```
-f, --force ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
```

Answer (score 2):

The greatest what I found is

```
\rm file
```

this will run the original unalias version and keep the alias intact.

We can also use shell built-in `command` for instance

`command rm file`

but I surely enjoy the less verbosity in first one

Comment: I use quotes to avoid aliases, e.g. `'rm' file` but yours is shorter!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get around the defined `alias` is to give the full path when you don't want to be prompted:

```
/bin/rm mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz
```

I like to leave an alias to `rm -i` in place for safety, for when I'm hacking around in the middle of the night and typing `rm ...`.  But when I'm alert enough to remember that I don't want to be prompted, I type `/bin/rm ...`.

Comment: You can also do `command rm /dead/file`. `command` executes it without searching functions or aliases.